# Jenkins Build Trigger after each commit to Github

Tags: jenkins, triggers, build-triggers

I want to set in Jenkins jobs triggering Build after each commit
I dont have access to Setting in my repository on Github, so I don't have possibility using WebHook.

What is the best/.easy way to set this in other way?

I have jobs for private repository Github, and clone project by SSH 
I also using Github Oauth Token

Jenkins Continuous Integration Server is on running on a Ubuntu host

Answer (score 0):

You can use local git hook pre-push. It runs after you issue the "git push" command. (but executes before pushing)

See example: [pre-push hook](https://github.com/git/git/blob/87c86dd14abe8db7d00b0df5661ef8cf147a72a3/templates/hooks--pre-push.sample)